# Top links are not showing in header in magento?

Tags: magento

echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks')

by putting this code in header.phtml, the toplinks are not showing in the home page.
I am using the custom theme on home page only, and the links are showing every where else in the site accept on home page.
I cheked all the solution but not getting the exact answer.
i checked all the xml and phtml files if there any code commented but all the files are fine.
I also checked from the backend but there also everything is enable, so what can i do now.
Please help me with this.

Comment: can you share your code of header.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

In page.xml, ensure that:

> ```
> <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
> ```

is within:

> ```
> <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
> ```

You might find that enabling template path hints in the Magento admin will help you see if the topLinks block is being called on your home page.

Also, if you have caching on, I would refresh it (System->Cache Management). In fact, if you're making several changes, it might be worth temporarily disabling caching to prevent running into cache problems.